# Why is this prepared insert into MySql with PDO inserting wrong value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, prepared-statement

I am trying to seed a database table with map points reflecting each point in a jpg map. The code is a test with  tiny 3x7 image, but the application is  intended for much larger maps, in which map point information will associated with each point and stored in the table. The map_terrain field represents the color hex value for a given coordinate. But it is the associated x,y values that are going wrong.

I am ending up with each row in the table with map_point_x = 7 and map_point_y = 3. The map_terrain field has the correct values.

How is this going astray?

```
$image_filespec = '../test.jpg';
$map_id = 1;

include_once '../includes/functions.php';

function heximagecolorat($image, $x, $y, $sharp_prefix = TRUE) {

        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);

        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

   If ($sharp_prefix == TRUE) {
       $hex = "#";
   } else {
       $hex = "";
   }
   $hex .= str_pad(dechex($r), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
   $hex .= str_pad(dechex($g), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
   $hex .= str_pad(dechex($b), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

   return $hex; // returns the hex value including the number sign (#)
}


if ($image_filespec == 'nnn.jpg' ){
    echo 'you need to edit teh php file to make this work and alter $image_filespec as appropriate';
    return;
}


//$result = query_db('SELECT * FROM users');
//  
//while($row = $result->fetch()){
//    echo $row['uID'] . " - " . $row['uUsername'] . "<br/>";
//}

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_filespec); // imagecreatefromjpeg/png/

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$colors = array();


for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {

    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {

        $colors[] = heximagecolorat($image, $x, $y, $sharp_prefix=FALSE) ; 
    } 
}

// connect and insert arrya to database $row in this context is talking about table row as opposed to row from the original image
$dbh = db_connect();

$query = "INSERT INTO map_points (  map_id, map_point_x, map_point_y, map_terrain ) VALUES "; //Prequery
$qPart = array_fill(0, count($colors), "( ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query .=  implode(",",$qPart);
$stmt = $dbh -> prepare($query); 
$i = 1;

$point=0;
for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) { //bind the values one by one
        $stmt -> bindParam($i++, $map_id);
        $stmt -> bindParam($i++, $x);
        $stmt -> bindParam($i++, $y);
        $stmt -> bindParam($i++, $colors[$point]);
        $point += 1;
    }
}
$temp=$stmt;
$stmt -> execute(); //execute
```

Comment: Could be an issue of [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) vs [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) `bindParam() -> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.`

Comment: I'll check into that @Sean but surely the same thing would have occurred with the last bindParam when meaning $point would have had value 20. All of the individual values from the colors array have been inserted however.

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook: it does not occur for `$point` because it is used as an array index, so the variable `$point` itself is never bound to the prepared statement.

Comment: Not necessarily.  With `$x` and `$y` you are overwritting the previous value with each loop, but since `$point` is the key of `$colors` you are looping through each array value and never overwrite the previous array value.

Comment: And indeed you are correct that bindvalue works. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the use of [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](https://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam): this binds the value of the variables (like `$x`, `$y`, ...) *at the moment of query execution*. This will be the final values after the loops, i.e. `3` and `7` in your example.

Use [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](https://php.net/pdostatement.bindvalue) instead.

Additionally, it may be more easy to read and maintain your code if you execute the statement for each point, instead of using as many tuples as there are rows. In other words, use multiple `INSERT INTO map_points(map_id, map_point_x, map_point_y, map_terrain) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)` instead of one `INSERT INTO map_points(map_id, map_point_x, map_point_y, map_terrain) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), ...`. Multiple tuples have better performance, but a similar performance can be reached by wrapping the INSERT statements in a transaction.

```
$dbh = db_connect();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO map_points (map_id, map_point_x, map_point_y, map_terrain) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$y = 0;
$x = 0;
$stmt->bindValue(1, $map_id);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $x);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $y);
$dbh->beginTransaction();
for (; $y < $height; $y++) {
    for (; $x < $width; $x++) {
        $stmt->bindValue(4, heximagecolorat($image, $x, $y, $sharp_prefix=FALSE));
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
$dbh->commit();
```

Comment: Easier to read @Tomas Creemers but I read that this has a performance impact and final maps maybe around 8000 x 4000 pixels. I suspect there will be limits exceeded here, but that is a later problem and I will batch the inserts to stay within limits.

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook: it is true that inserting multiple tuples has better performance (as I mentioned). Wrapping multiple INSERT statements in one transaction has nearly the same effect, since the input will only be written at the time `commit()` is called.

Comment: I missed what you said about wrapping in a transaction. Does a transaction imply a set of memory based inserts, then applied as a single database interaction, as opposed to multiple HDD based inserts.  I had thought the purpose of transactions was to implement roll back in the case of failure of a single element.

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook: you are correct: a transaction offers the benefit of being able to roll back. MySQL is also smart enough to optimize a transaction by using memory instead of disk (up to a point, see [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size]) until the transaction is committed. MySQL can do this because an uncommitted transaction does not need to be permanent yet (i.e. it can avoid slow writing to disk).